# Is Shimano GRX Di2 Bluetooth compatible?

Tags: shifter, shimano-di2, grx

Can I connect Shimano GRX Di2 via Bluetooth to E tube project software?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, but with an optional module (EW-WU111) or a screen that has bluetooth connectivity. If your bike doesn't have it, you can install it afterwards.

The following video explains how to do it.